# Reinitialize ng-model data after closing a modal

Tags: angular

i am using Angular 2 with modals. After closing the modal and reopening it, all the old data are still available. But i want to reset all data. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

Your are closing the modals. so, in your `close` function logic put code to reset the values.
It you are using `Component` for the `modals` then you can use lifeCycle hook 
`ngOnDestroy` to reset the values. Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your question has very poor description. But why wouldn't use straightforward way and just let user to interact with copy of model? Some pseudo code:

```
function onOpen() {
   this.tempModel = Object.assign({}, this.realModel);
   //or if you modal creates a new entity
   //this.tempModel = {};
}

function onReset () {
    //do nothing
}

function onSave () {
   this.realModel = this.tempModel
}
```